# How to change modem telnet password and web password via telnet?

Tags: linux, networking, router, modem

I currently reside in China and I use various VPN services to gain access to international internet. But the VPNs tend to get blocked themselves, so naturally I messed around with routers and stuff.

The current ISP I am using is China Telecom and the modem is HS8145C5, they change the admin password every time I register the modem using LOID, they block my VPN connections anytime through TR069 ACS and they didn't provide LOID, my PPPoE password and even the PPPoE account!

But I have physical access to the modem which means I can push the reset button, every time I reset the modem, I lost internet access but I gain admin access using the default account `telecomadmin` and password `nE7jA%5m` which of course the ISP didn't provide me.

I was able to obtain the LOID, but every time I register the modem I gain internet access and lose admin access to the modem, because they change the admin password to random strings as soon as you register modem.

But I was able to enable telnet and obtain web admin password using this mess I have found:

```
telnet 192.168.1.1
root
adminHW
su
shell
cp /mnt/jffs2/hw_ctree.xml /mnt/jffs2/mycfg.xml.gz 
cd /mnt/jffs2
aescrypt2 1 mycfg.xml.gz tem
gzip -d mycfg.xml.gz
grep WebUserInfoInstance mycfg.xml
rm mycfg.xml
```

The account is `root` and password is `adminHW`. The second last line outputs something like this:

```
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="1" ModifyPasswordFlag="0" UserName="useradmin" Password="$2!ZM$Idyl@J~}&gt;8&apos;n6KWMF|-@Koy&gt;C,;ofJBq_&apos;V5$" UserLevel="1" Enable="1" Alias="cpe-1"/>
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="2" ModifyPasswordFlag="1" UserName="telecomadmin" Password="$2:8jUNk0n|HenK~CB|&apos;^&amp;Aopi&quot;&lt;v~xJmC&amp;&lt;!TXx`3$" UserLevel="0" Enable="1" Alias="cpe-2" PassMode="0"/>
```

The password is encrypted and I don't know the format, but I was able to decrypt it using this [tool](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17A5-UpR06jqQV6doMq1Ks9J_eVSTY7I6/view?usp=share_link) I found (paste password into the textbox under Text Decryption label, and click <kbd>$2</kbd>), I was able to obtain the new admin password.

I was then able to find the PPPoE account, and the password after <kbd>F12</kbd> and changing inputbox `type` from `"password"` to `"text"`.

But the password I got is a 64-bit hexadecimal string, which after some digging turns out to be `SHA256(MD5(pwd))`, so I wrote this Python program to bruteforce the password:

```python
from hashlib import md5, sha256

count = 0
reversemap = dict()

def guess(s):
    if s in reversemap:
        return reversemap[s]
    
    global count
    for n in range(count, 1000000000):
        i = str(n)
        digest = sha256(md5(i.encode()).hexdigest().encode()).hexdigest()
        reversemap[digest] = i
        if digest == s:
            count = n + 1
            break
    
    return i
```

I was able to get the password, but it is useless because I cannot delete TR069 WAN connection no matter what...

But I have `su` telnet access, and I was able to change ISP interface to factory interface using this script I found:

```
cp -f /mnt/jffs2/hw_ctree.xml /mnt/jffs2/hw_ctree_bak.xml
cp -f /mnt/jffs2/hw_boardinfo /mnt/jffs2/hw_boardinfo_bak
cp -f /etc/wap/hw_default_ctree.xml /mnt/jffs2/hw_ctree.xml
sed -i 's/^.*obj.id = "0x0000001a" ; obj.value =.*$/obj.id = "0x0000001a" ; obj.value = "COMMON";/' /mnt/jffs2/hw_boardinfo
sed -i 's/^.*obj.id = "0x0000001b" ; obj.value =.*$/obj.id = "0x0000001b" ; obj.value = "COMMON";/' /mnt/jffs2/hw_boardinfo
sed -i 's/^.*obj.id = "0x00000031" ; obj.value =.*$/obj.id = "0x00000031" ; obj.value = "NOCHOOSE";/' /mnt/jffs2/hw_boardinfo
reboot
```

I was then able to gain access to internet by setting the modem to bridge mode and dial using the router, and delete TR069 WAN connection and disable ACS and periodic report and invalidate the auto-report logins...

And then I have unobstructed VPN connections! But it did not last long...

Somehow the ISP can change my modem's settings, which makes sense because I didn't change the passwords, and I haven't been able to find a way to change them...

But according to the code, the configs are stored in `/mnt/jffs2/hw_ctree.xml`, which is a .xml file that is gzipped and then aescrypted, so if I can just change that one line, gzip the .xml, AES encrypt it, and rename the resulting file to `/mnt/jffs2/hw_ctree.xml`, that can work.

I found I can use the following lines to `aescrypt2(gzip())` and replace the original file:

```
gzip /mnt/jffs2/mycfg.xml
aescrypt2 0 /mnt/jffs2/mycfg.xml.gz tem
cp -f /mnt/jffs2/mycfg.xml.gz /mnt/jffs2/hw_ctree.xml
```

But I don't know how to edit the file...

And more importantly, after changing interface, the two lines containing login info are different:

```
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="1" ModifyPasswordFlag="0" UserName="useradmin" Password="$2*P#&lt;Rm12MIRDkTTWT1NLn01YXTlMwFM]&gt;d=_$|A$0&amp;VND3OIl~fvHI$bbo8Su&gt;jVP)^v]MiPG&gt;.u9&apos;{N6n)]=cIhB0+&gt;tG1IS|9R$" UserLevel="1" Enable="1" Alias="cpe-1" Salt="deeb9e44dc1b96caaa9c312d" PassMode="3"/> 
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="2" ModifyPasswordFlag="0" UserName="telecomadmin" Password="$2ha17UJ3)&amp;/*k,o-D8Y1PJF:(4b^vWVK}$5:+UQ_0BJLWCDy:AGaY:~!_dBc&apos;*E5DRc#De56S=r&apos;dUHwUMP=b/h3V3:Fd^XB_MQ`N$" UserLevel="0" Enable="1" Alias="cpe-2" Salt="180cf7332c754daddf2d42f2" PassMode="3"/>
```

The password encryption are apparently salted, and using the tool I found cannot decrypt them, but I know they are encrypted and not hashed, and the first one decrypts to `zvsmc` the second one decrypts to `nE7jA%5m`, and I guess the encryption is AES.

I need to know how to encrypt the password using the same encryption used by the modem.

And I cannot change telnet password as well, the modem is BusyBox v1.26.2 (Dopra Linux) according to the prompt, and below is what happened when I tried to change password:

```
Login:root
Password:
WAP>passwd
ERROR::Command is not existed

WAP>su
success!
SU_WAP>passwd
ERROR::Command is not existed

SU_WAP>shell

BusyBox v1.26.2 () built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

profile close core dump
WAP(Dopra Linux) # passwd
passwd: no record of srv_ssmp in /etc/shadow, using /etc/passwd
Changing password for srv_ssmp
Old password:
Incorrect password
passwd: password for srv_ssmp is unchanged
WAP(Dopra Linux) #
WAP(Dopra Linux) # passwd root
passwd: srv_ssmp can't change password for root
```

I have obtained a list of commands present in the modem: [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kz6FvdGgLIv9O_gI3mi5NQiiiQimeGUc/view?usp=share_link)

How can I change the passwords so that my ISP cannot change my modem's settings? The modem also has a USB port which can be used to backup and restore settings.

---

I was able to obtain the configuration file of the modem and I know how to put it back.

[hw_ctree.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_5rF3YxK_XXGgdJ7plYvAyduJSWPFsh1/view?usp=share_link)

What can I change in it?

---

I have found out that Huawei uses DES encryption, and the method to decrypt it: [script](https://gist.github.com/staaldraad/605a5e40abaaa5915bc7)

I am trying to reverse engineer it.

Comment: did you tried to upgrade the firmware after reset? or downgrade to a version that do not have any auto conf feature from ISP?

Comment: I have no knowledge of your router, but this seams fairly stanfard linux to me & in which case if you can modify /etc/shadow (which may be an overly somewhere underneath /jffs2) jffs is a : seperated text file - you just need to find a way to hash the password and replace the sexond xolumn with the password hash.

Comment: MD5 and SHA256 are **hashing** algorithms not encryption, they cannot be decrypted, the only approach is brute force. It would be unusual for a Linux kernel to use encryption on passwords, as it would allow what you are attempting to do, which is the reason you’re unable to do what you are attempting to do. One approach that might work, is replacing the hexadecimal representation in the password shadow file with one you know the password to since passwd doesn’t seem to exist on the system

Comment: @Ramhound I knew SHA256 and MD5 are hashing algorithms, I knew they are one way functions that are highly improbable to compute in the reverse direction, but I know PPPoE passwords in my area are just strings of a several decimal digits, so I did preimage attack on it, in this case the string is `4f5f282e7e716424bcd5b5a10a82d7acabc87a0ae07ee88d9fd8ae69bbfbbfc9` and `12345678` is the actual PPPoE password. I just don't know the encryption method for the HTTP login password and how to change the telnet login password.